# AWS Lambda Nodejs connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I would like to use AWS Lambda function to connect to a MySQL instance, but I find loads of instructions on how to do this with .js files, but now the default is with .mjs (node js modules), so it's NOT the typical `require('mysql')` syntax as specified there:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction

`import ?????? from "mysql";`

How do I connect to mysql using **AWS Lambda Function** with **node.js module** structure?

Comment: I found my own answer: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/clients/client-rds-data/README.md

Comment: Maybe not, after jumping all the hoops, it now says that the Data API must be enabled, but that only available in "serverless v1", and there is no option to create a serverless v1 rds server... so it's a no go

Answer (score 0):

File names ending in .cjs are always treated as CommonJS modules. File names ending in .mjs are always treated as ES modules. File names ending in .js inherit their [type](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type) from the package.json:

```
// package.json for ES Modules
{
  "name": "esm-example",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "This package will be treated as an ES module.",
  "main": "index.js",
}

// package.json for CommonJS
{
  "name": "cjs-example",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "description": "This package will be treated as CommonJS",
  "main": "index.js",
}
```

In your case, the equivalent of `var mysql = require('mysql');` using `import` is:

```js
import mysql from 'mysql';
```